# Implement my own Email server in my machine

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, smtp, sendmail

I'm very new to Email server config field.

I have 10 000 Email address in my database. My only requirement is send a mail to each and every email address. But I do not need to receive any mail(not need static IP). I know it is not possible with common mails like Gmail or hotmail. How can I do it ?

I have tried SMTP. Installed IIS 7. When I going to config the SMTP it ask a email address. I believe that it is act as a client and foreword mails to real Email server.

How can I implement my own Email server in my machine ? Or if I use Linux kernel how the things happening ?

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... we're talking about sending a mailing, right? :]

Hey, it's 2012, where in the middle of SPAM war! I'm more than 100% sure that you'll waste lot of time and end up with noting or with your e-mail account blocked by your ISP for sending out e-mail. Because you will have to use your existing SMTP server / account for encrypted sendout or your own, local server will only be able to use port 25, which is blocked on most destination servers.

Want to know the best solution? Find any site (like freelancer.com), where you can offer a one-time job of sending your e-mail do these recipients and pay for it. This is the simplest, fastest and low-nervous way. And it should be fairly cheap for only 10k addresses (I found some Hindi company on freelancer, where I paid 10$ (ten bucks!) for a mailing to 500k+ addresses, though quality and time of doing this job was really poor).

I had the very same issue. I wasted few hours for trying to setup own mail server or use some specific mailing piece of software. I considered many solutions, waste too much time and ended up getting someone from freelancer.com to do the job for me and paid for it.

You can also consider a professional mail sending service, like for example [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/pricing/free/).

MailChimp allows you to send up to 12 000 e-mail per month absolutely free (as a demo of their paid services). But since you can have only 2k addresses in your address book per once, you would have to split your 10k database into five parts and send out whole mailing in five days long period. But still, free.

Comment: You're welcome. And good luck. For your needs MailChimps seems to be best solution.